# Supertest: api with "await" was blocked

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, mocha.js, supertest

I use supertest, chai and mocha to run api-testing. I have the following code:

- app.js

```
app.get('/post', async (req, res, next) => {
    await postModel.find();
    console.log("co xuong duoi la duoc");
    res.json({loi: "hi"}).status(200)

    // postModel.find(() => res.json({loi: "hi"}).status(200));
    //;
})
```

- test.js

```
describe('GET /post', () => {

    before(() => {
        db.connect()
            // .then(() => done())
            // .catch((err) => done(err));
    })

    it('OK nha', (done) => {
        request(app).get('/post').then((res) => {
            const body = res.body;
            console.log(body);
            expect(body).to.deep.property('loi');
            done();
        })
        .catch(error => done(error));
    })
})
```

When I run npm test, the code was blocked in line **await postModel.find()**. Then, the terminal showed: "For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."

But if i comment this line: **//await postModel.find()**. It worked.

The line: **console.log(body)** was run.

Please help me with this problem. Sorry for my English.

Comment: What is `postModel` and what does `postModel.find()` return?

Comment: I found the error. Mongodb connected failed. I fixed it. Thanks :D `postModel` is an model created by Post schema

Comment: Sure, but you didn't post any code of that - you didn't even tag the question [mongodb].

Comment: Because I don't think the error relate mongodb, and I only have 5 tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try to assert your issues with following factors

1. If you're using remote or local mongodb connection, please ensure all are up and running. If it remote it will take some amount of time to setup a connection. Because Mocha default timeout is just 5 seconds for test cases. It causes unhandled promise rejection error and then this error may shown to you.
2. Create simple `await setTimeout(dummyPostData, 5000)` in API service code and observe that test case is passing or not.

Finally please update your question did you get any db error connection error or any timeout related exception. So it will help us debug the issues.

Comment: I found the error. Mongodb connected failed. I fixed it. Thanks :D